# Laravel - Shared data reduce number of queries

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I am trying to make a global search feature on my website, and for that I need to query the database to get the records. The frontend of my application expect the following array:

```
[
 ['name' => 'Result #1...', 'url' => 'http://...'],
 ['name' => 'Result #2...', 'url' => 'http://...'],
 ['name' => 'Result #3...', 'url' => 'http://...'],
]
```

To accomplish this, I have added the below in my `AppServiceProvider`:

```php
public function boot()
{
    view()->composer('*', function($view) use ($auth) {
            return \View::share('SearchData', (new GlobalSearch($auth->user()->currentTeam))->all());
    });
}
```

The `$SearchData` is created in the `GlobalSearch` class:

```php
class GlobalSearch
{
    public $data;

    public function __construct(public Team $team){
        $this->data = $team->properties()->with(['leases', 'leases.tenant', 'leases.files', 'leases.invoices']);
    }


    protected function propertyData() : array
    {
    
        $properties = $this->data->get();

        return $properties->map(function ($property) {
            $array['name'] = \Str::limit($property->address, 40);
            $array['url'] = route('properties.show', ['property' => $property]);
            
            return $array;
        })->toArray();    


    }


    public function all() : array
    {
       return $this->propertyData();
    }
}
```

Now the above code does work - I successfully get an array in the correct mapping. However, in my database I only have **1** property in the `properties` table - yet, there are being executed 90 duplicate queries for a single page load.

**Why is this happening? I can't seem to locate why these queries are being duplicated**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can actually remove the `view()->composer('*', function)` part. Since `View::share()` does the exact same.

```php
$searchData = (new GlobalSearch($auth->user()->currentTeam))->all();
View::share('SearchData', $searchData);
```

Optionally:

You could bind the `GlobalSearch` class to the container in your `AppServiceProvider`. Which will make the class available via `app(GlobalSearch::class)` wherever you want in the application. This means the query will only run once during the initialization process and maintain the data.

More info about singleton bindings: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/container#binding-a-singleton

```php
$this->app->singleton(GlobalSearch::class, function ($app) {
    return new GlobalSearch(auth()->user()->team);
});
```